# File rename in batch in Unix

Tags: unix

Hi I have file in my directory as below:

```
ewPrd030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores_cache.ver
ewPrd030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores.Count_cache.dat
```

I need to rename as below:

```
ewPpt030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores_cache.ver
ewPpt030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores.Count_cache.dat
```

Can you please let me the know a one liner that can do this?

Comment: Is this Unix or Linux? Which Unix? Which Linux? What shell do you use? Do you want to do this for one file or for many similar files?

Comment: You're just changing occurrences of `rd` to `pt`?

Comment: Its Unix, Shell: SHELL=/bin/ksh
 Yes i want to change occurrence of rd to pt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename many files, do something like this:

```
for f in *Prd*;do mv "$f" "${f/Prd/Ppt}"; done
```

This will go through all files whose name contains `Prd` in the current directory and rename them. It takes advantage of bash's (I am assuming you are using bash) [string substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) capabilities.

Comment: Hi my question was to replace Prd to Ppt.

Comment: @Yugesh sorry, answer updated. What operating system are you using? Which Unix? `rename` might be better if it is available to you. Also, this assumes you are using `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

rename can be used for batch renaming files

With your example:

```
$ rename -v 's/^ewPrd/ewPpt/' *ActiveStores*
ewPrd030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores_cache.ver renamed as ewPpt030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores_cache.ver
ewPrd030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores.Count_cache.dat renamed as ewPpt030MmCommonEaiClcBroker034_RSS.ActiveStores.Count_cache.dat
```

Comment: Careful, there are various implementations of rename and they have different formats. Since the OP has not mentioned his OS, this may well not work for him. +1 one though cause that's certainly not your fault.

Comment: Hi, the rename command is not working. it is throwing below error:ksh: rename:  not found

Comment: On my system (debian 7) rename is a perl script (provided by the perl package). rename.ul is also installed and works for me (provided by util-linux).